# Selecting the similar cells in Excel using Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I am automating a webpage using Selenium but there is one scenario where after clicking on a button, it opens up an Excel sheet. I need to enter a value in the cell of the Excel sheet. I am using Sikuli (in Eclipse) to do that but the header name of the cell is not unique. (Please refer the screenshot)

[image: Reference screenshot. Trying to enter value in the cell highlighted in red box.]

I am trying to enter the value in the cell highlighted in red box.

I tried the below code (in Eclipse) but it is clicking the wrong cell.

```
Screen s = new Screen();    
Pattern p = new Pattern("images/Cell.png");
s.find(p);
s.click(p);
```

**Cell.png** is as below:

[image: Cell.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reference I am giving the 3rd option That I tried and worked for me in addition to the 2 answers given by @timfredo & @chathuD.

I included the nearby cells to make the Cell.png unique. refer the screenshot below.

**Previously Cell.png was as follows:**

[image]

**To make Cell.png unique I changed it to the below:**

[image]

Now to click on the desired cell I used the following code.

```
Screen s = new Screen();    
Pattern p = new Pattern("images/Cell.png");

/*This will highlight the selected area for 3 seconds.*/
s.find(p).below(25).right(-200).left(5).highlight(3);

s.find(p).below(25).right(-200).left(5).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

After your code get executed it will click on some point in the Excel sheet.
Then use keyboard key pressing to navigate to the correct cell.
Then enter the values .

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Some cells are write-protected navigating through the keyboard keys keeps giving error msg.

Comment: What about open the same file as a xlm or csv and then entering the appropriate data.

Comment: Actually I cannot control in which format the sheet opens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python scripting to solve this and use the [findall method](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.findAll) of the Region object. This gives you a list of all matching images and then you can click/fill only the second occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. your solution worked but I found another way used that in my code. i.e offsetting by using the following. I included the neighboring cell also in the cell.png and used `s.find(N_Hash_Region).below(25).right(-200).left(5).click();`